# CassandraDaemon.java:709 - Exception encountered during startup java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown CF

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

We have a 15 node cassandra setup across 3 DC's.
Using cassandra 3.0.9

One of the nodes in one of our DCs  has died with the below startup error

CassandraDaemon.java:709 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown CF 111111-111111111-11111111

What we have tried -

Bootstrap replacing the node -https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsReplaceNode.html

This works for a while and then the bootstrap process hangs with the SAME error in the logs -
 CassandraDaemon.java:709 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown CF

Provision a new blank node, 
https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsAddNodeToCluster.html

and try to join this to the cluster (with the intention of removing the dead node after).  It refuses to start, with the same error.

has anyone ever ran across this before?

Comment: This error appears to be complaining about a non-existent column family (table).  Do you have some odd directory in your data directory that should not be there? I would check each node to see if that directory (5471ee...) exists in the data directory. Also, it may be helpful to see the lines before (and anything after) that may appear in the system.log or debug.log.

Comment: Are the other 14 nodes in schema agreement?  if not, give them a bounce and try to re-add.

Comment: yes, if i do a describe cluster all the nodes are in agreement, and this one node (05) is unreachable,   Im struggling to figure out how to fix this problem.  The stack shows it is trying to build a view, based on an outdated base table id.  I have dropped the view from the other nodes, but this obviously hasnt propogated to this one node (as it's offline....)

Comment: One thing, if i try replacing the node, The new replacement node gets a different schema ID to the rest, and then fails halfway through with pretty much the same error.

Comment: If i look on my other 14 nodes, in the /data directory I can see the folder for the table, but it has the OLD ID, not the new ID (even tho if i check in cqslh in the system-schema.tables the new ID is there) ,   So do I need to do a flush or something to get this updated?  What i believe is happening when i try replace the node, is the other nodes are send that data with the old ID, and the new node is like, what is this?

Comment: At this point, try a `nodetool assassinateendpoint` to get the old node out of the other nodes' gossip.  Then try re-joining it, and see if that helps.